# How to pin a Command Prompt and get it to open with a certain folder?

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I've pinned a Command Prompt to the taskbar. I set it to open in Administrator mode.  When I click on it, it opens in `c:\windows\system32`.

I'd like it to start in `c:\code`.  To that end, I right-clicked on the pinned icon, selected properties and changed the value in the `Start in` textbox to `c:\code` directory.  However, it's not having the right effect.

So how can I get a pinned Command Prompt window to open in a certain directory?

Comment: What do u mean by "right effect"?

Comment: @Nikhar I mean, the Command Window still opens in c:\windows\system32

Comment: Just create a shortcut on the desktop, change the "Start in" entry to to "c:\code" of that shortcut and it will open in that..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you edit the Properties of the pinned Command Prompt, instead of changing the "Start In" value, add the following to the "Target" value:

```
/K cd C:\code
```

So that your target should look something like:

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /K cd C:\code
```

You can also Shift+Right-Click in any open Explorer window and click "Open Command Window Here" to open a Command Prompt from any open folder, if you didn't know.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for.